# Invoke-WebRequest not showing the desired information

Tags: powershell

I am trying to pull the current version numbers from the google chrome page [Chrome Download](https://enterprise.google.com/intl/en_version/chrome/chrome-browser/#)

Using Invoke-Web request I can get ton's of information from the site, just not that one bit of info that I'm looking for

This is the closest I have been able to get, it is the line but I guess I need to show the class name to get what I want

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "https://enterprise.google.com/intl/en_version/chrome/chrome-browser/"
($WebResponse.ParsedHtml.getElementById("main")| foreach{$_.getElementsByTagName("span")})[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use omahaproxy for that , you will be able to get a csv with chrome version details for each platform and you can parse it like this :

```
$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/all" 
$csv = $WebResponse.Content | convertfrom-csv

($csv | ?{($_.os -eq 'win64') -and ($_.channel -eq 'stable')}).current_version
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't even know this was an option. Just out of interest though, in case I would like to do it for other projects. Is what I was trying to do even possible?

Comment: @LiamMatthews this would be the code for that `$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "https://enterprise.google.com/intl/en_version/chrome/chrome-browser/"; 
($webresponse.parsedhtml.getElementsByTagName("div")| Where {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'version'}).outerhtml` if you see the output it will only have loading.I am assuming they are using some ajax call to get that